# Format Date() in VFP report

Tags: visual-foxpro

I use  database program written in VFP and I am trying to change a date format in a report generated by that program.
The current field in the report is DATE() which returns DD/MM/YYYY
I'd like the field to return DDMMYY (ie no seperators, no century and single digit days and months to have a leading zero)
Can someone tell me the report field expression I should use to achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by creating a procedure and call that procedure as 
date2(date(), "", 2, 2, 2) in report field.

This will print 150418

This function can also be used with default value i.e. date(date()) which will print 15-Apr-18

```
FUNCTION date2(par_date, par_separtor, par_day_digit, par_month_digit, par_year_digit)
    LOCAL date_return, day_t, month_t, year_t
    IF VARTYPE(par_separtor) <> "C"
        par_separtor    = "-"
    ENDIF
    IF VARTYPE(par_year_digit) <> "N"
        par_year_digit  = 2
    ENDIF
    day_t       = IIF(DAY(par_date)<10, '0', "") + allt(str(DAY(par_date)))
    month_t     = PROPER(allt(left(CMONTH(par_date),3)))
    year_t      = right(allt(str(year(par_date))),par_year_digit)
    IF VARTYPE(par_month_digit) = "N"
        month_t = IIF(MONTH(par_date)<10, '0', "") + allt(STR(MONTH(par_date)))
*       MESSAGEBOX(month)
    ENDIF

    date_return = IIF(EMPTY(par_date), "         ",  day_t + par_separtor + month_t + par_separtor + year_t)
    RETURN date_return
ENDFUNC
```

Answer (score 0):

Before report set the century off if it is not already (you could do this even if you only have access to report itself, either in report environment or bands code):

```
Set century off
```

Then the expression is simply:

```
CHRTRAN(DTOC(DATE()),'/','')
```

Or if you meant a date field:

```
CHRTRAN(DTOC(myDateField),'/','')
```

If, for any reason, you can't use "set century off" (and it is ON) then change the expression slightly:

```
Stuff(CHRTRAN(DTOC(myDateField),'/',''),5,2,'')
```

Maybe this one is better and works regardless of date/datetime settings:

```
PADL(DAY(DATE())*10000+MONTH(DATE())*100+YEAR(DATE())%100,6,'0')
```

(if it is a date fieldthen replace date() with the field name)

Comment: Hi Cetin. Brilliant. The last solution works a treat!